# Doctrine 2 Lifecycle event that always fires when persist is called

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Is there a Doctrine 2 lifecycle event I can subscribe that will always fire any time I call `persist()` and  `flush()` on an entity.

I am looking to generate a cache file based on an entity any time a user 'saves' that entity, regardless of whether or not Doctrine will actually issue an SQL update statement.

The workaround I'm considering is to add an extra field that's always out of sync with the database to force a persist/update, but I'd prefer an event that is always called.

BTW:

- The code that performs the persist of the entity is within a third party bundle and I'd rather not hack it if I can avoid that.

Comment: Have you tried [prePersist](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events) (for inserts) + preUpdate (for updates)? If so, what issues have you met.

Comment: I have - the problem is that these don't get fired if there is no change in the entities persist-able state. This is a feature of doctrine to avoid unnecessary writes, but in this case its thwarting my efforts.

Comment: I'm currently using this:

Comment: `public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args)
    {
        $args->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->getIdentityMap();`

Comment: This gives a list of all entities that are current managed. It's not quite what I want but I can use it.